# Trigger SQL calculated between two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have two table `PRODUCT` and `INVOICE`:

```
Create table PRODUCT(){
    PRODUCTID nvarchar(10), -- product id
    PRICE float,
}
Create table INVOICE(){
    PRODUCTID nvarchar(10),
    QUANTUM int,
    AMOUNT float,
}
```

Now I want create `Trigger` compute column `AMOUNT` on `INVOICE`, `AMOUNT` = `QUANTUM` * `PRICE`

Thank your help!

```
create trigger trig_INVOICE
on INVOICE
after insert, update
as
begin
   declare @price float
   declare @ProductId nvarchar(10)
   set @ProductID = (Select PRODUCTID from INVOICE)
   set @price = (Select PRICE from PRODUCT where PRODUCT.PRODUCTID = @ProductId)
   UPDATE INVOICE set AMOUNT = QUANTUM * @price
end
```

It's not work -_-

Comment: What engine is this?  mySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: What have to tried so far?

Comment: why you need a column for that, create a view to have that Calculated Amount value?

Comment: You are setting @price to the first value in PRODUCT and you are not relating it to the ProductID in INVOICE.

Comment: Removed the `mysql` tag, because MySQL doesn't have `nvarchar` and the sample trigger looks more like T-SQL

Comment: your invoice table should have primary key INVOICEID ?

Comment: `float` is a poor choice of a data type if you're dealing with currencies. In addition, are you sure you need to *store* `Amount`? If it's always just `quantum * price` then that would be better dealt with via a view (possibly an indexed view if performance matters) - in general, don't *store* computed values when you can just perform the calculation later and always get the correct answer, with no maintenance required.

Answer (score 0):

Add `InvoiceID` column in `Invoice` Table as Primary Key.

Add Trigger on `INVOICE` Table

```
CREATE TRIGGER invoice_trg 
   ON  dbo.INVOICE AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    UPDATE INVOICE
    SET    AMOUNT = INVOICE.QUANTUM * PRODUCT.price
    FROM   INVOICE 
    INNER JOIN PRODUCT ON INVOICE.PRODUCTID = PRODUCT.PRODUCTID
    INNER JOIN INSERTED ON INVOICE.PRODUCTID = INSERTED.PRODUCTID

END
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a primary key to the Invoice table, lets say InvID, then you should be able to use the trigger below.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig_INVOICE ON INVOICE
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE  INVOICE
    SET     AMOUNT = QUANTUM * Price
    FROM    inserted ins
            INNER JOIN invoice
            ON InvID = InvID
            INNER JOIN Product
            ON inserted.ProductID = Product.ProductID;
END;/
```

Answer (score 0):

Trigger is not going to execute for each `Row`. Change your trigger like this.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig_INVOICE
ON INVOICE
after INSERT, UPDATE
AS
  BEGIN
      UPDATE a
      SET    AMOUNT = QUANTUM * p.price
      FROM   INVOICE a
             JOIN inserted b
               ON a.PRODUCTID = b.PRODUCTID
             JOIN PRODUCT p
               ON a.PRODUCTID = p.PRODUCTID
  END
```